# Adding php filter to redirect to current web page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am attempting to add a piece of code that redirects the user to the current site when using the Simple Membership Plugin on WordPress. This is the code I am currently using which is being inserted as a Snippet in php.

```
add_filter('swpm_before_login_form_submit_button', 'login_form_addition');
function login_form_addition($output) {
    //Add any extra text message or input fields to the login form output.
    $output .= '<input type="hidden" id="swpm_redirect_to" name="swpm_redirect_to" value =';
        echo (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    "/>";
    return $output; 
}
```

I know I could hardcode the value website but looking to do this dynamically. I'm not familiar with the php syntax, so cannot work out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Echo is not concatenation

```
add_filter('swpm_before_login_form_submit_button', 'login_form_addition');
function login_form_addition($output) {
    //Add any extra text message or input fields to the login form output.
    $output .= '<input type="hidden" id="swpm_redirect_to" name="swpm_redirect_to" value =';
        echo (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    "/>";
    return $output; 
}
```

The problem in the above code is `echo` - as written output will have the following appended to it:

```
<input type="hidden" id="swpm_redirect_to" name="swpm_redirect_to" value =
```

In the page source (at the top, probably) will be the rest of the content.

To correct, change echo for concatenation:

```
$output .= '<input type="hidd... value =' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])...;
```

Or write any other way that is functionally equivalent, e.g.:

```
$value = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

$output .= sprintf(
    '<input type="hidden" id="swpm_redirect_to" name="swpm_redirect_to" value="%s" />', 
    $value
);

return $output;
```